# Find Equation of Motion given Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, time-evolution

So I am given a harmonic oscillator in an electric field.  At $t=0$, we are given that the oscillator is in the ground state.  The Hamiltonian is:

$$H=\hbar \omega[a^{\dagger}a+\frac12+\kappa E_0\cos(\omega t)(a+a^{\dagger}) $$
$$\psi(t=0)=|0\rangle$$
We know that
$$\psi(r,t)=\sum_n a_n(t)e^{-i\omega_n t}\phi_n(r)$$
And then to get the time evolution, we use:
$$i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\psi=\hat H\psi$$
Where so I go from here.  I do not have an expression for the $a_n$, which makes this difficult to solve for

Comment: But you do know how $a|n\rangle$ and $a^\dagger|n\rangle$ behave, yes?

Comment: YEah.  $$a|n\rangle=\sqrt{n}|n-1\rangle$$$$a^{\dagger}|n\rangle=\sqrt{n+1}|n+1\rangle$$

Comment: Now what do you know of the time evolution operator?

Comment: Like $$U(t,to)=exp(-\frac{i}{\hbar}\int_{t_0}^t H(t')dt')$$

Comment: I normally see it as $U(t,t_0)=\exp\left[-iH(t-t_0)/\hbar\right]$ which is applied to states: $|\psi(t)\rangle=U(t,t_0)|\psi(t_0)\rangle$.

Comment: Should I be using a time dependent PT approach to this?

Comment: Well your Hamiltonian takes the form of a harmonic oscillator ($a^\dagger a+\frac12$) plus a time-dependent operator, so TDPT does seem applicable here.

Comment: Are you going to treat time dependent term as perturbation or are you going to solve it exactly?